# sql server roles with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables on my data base the first called **"Students"** which include information of the student and the second table called **"Study results"** which include the results of the student (the structure of each table is bellow)

> ==> table student
>
> id_student || name_student || age_student || absence_student
>
> ==> table study result
>
> id_result || id_student || subject_result || mark

I want that every student can be able to check his mark so I will give him a permission to only select from table **"Study results"** but I want also the student see only his mark not the mark of the other students something like [`select * from Study results where idstudent=student_a`]

can I do that ?
I hope you can understand my question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know id_student  of the current user? Do you have any function or something?

Comment: the student who logs in i will get his id

Comment: It is easier to enforce security with stored procedures as opposed to select permissions on the table.

Comment: can you please explain yourself i don't think that i get it

Answer (score 0):

You should create a stored procedure or a function which will return user's mark(s). For instance:

```
CREATE PROC GetUserMarks
    @UserId     INT
AS

DECLARE @pUserId INT = @UserId

SELECT subject_result, mark
FROM [study result]
WHERE id_student = @pUserId
```

And then run it using `id_student` of the current user as the variable `@UserId`